# MVC4 - Unable to find Twitterizer library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter, twitterizer

I'm working on a project that fetches data from a Twitter account specified in by the user. I've been writing some of the methods myself but I've seen in a tutorial video that there is (or should be) a library available called `Twitterizer` that helps with Twitter integration.
In the video, the programmer simply went into `Manage NuGet Packages` and performed a `Search Online` for `Twitterizer`, then installed the library when it was found.
I've tried both this method and using the `Package Manager Console` to install it using a command. Both ways I've tried, it hasn't been able to find `Twitterizer` at all.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be, or alternative ways of getting Twitterizer installed? Is it even still available?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitterizer source code is on GitHub:

https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer